# Functional testing with TheIntern: How do I test against my own site?

Tags: functional-testing, intern

I'm trying to get Intern setup to do functional testing for my site, but I feel like I'm running into conceptual wall.

The site is a single page app that gets built into a static site, then uploads to a remote server as the deployment process.

In my project directory, the final build artifacts live in `./build/prod`.

I've been through the docs for Intern 3.5 and the upcoming 4.0 alpha and its not clear exactly how to tell Intern to load `./build/prod` with its static http server and then run my tests against it.

I'm migrating from a webdriver.io setup, and with that we simply specify `baseURL` as the path to the static server hosting `./build/prod` and it runs the test suite.

Here is the sample configuration I've been working on with intern v4:

```
{
  "bail": false,
  "connectTimeout": 30000,
  "debug": true,
  "maxConcurrency": 4,
  "environments": [
    "chrome"
  ],
  "browser": {
    "suites": ["intern-tests/functional/**/*.js"]
  },
  "tunnel": "selenium",
  "tunnelOptions": {
    "drivers": ["chrome"]
  }
}
```

When this runs currently, Chrome is opened but Intern's sample tests run instead of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Functional suites should be listed in `functionalSuites` rather than `suites` in both Intern 3 and 4. To actually load a page in a functional test, you would call `this.remote.get(url)`, which is similar to calling `browser.url(url)` in Webdriver.io.